# SharpSVN: How to export several files from repository using a single command?

Tags: svn, sharpsvn

I have developed an application using SharpSVN API and .NET 4.0, where the user browses and selects some files from a SVN repository for a specific revision. Then the files are exported one by one in a temporary folder and zipped.

I am executing the SvnClient.Export method for each file and it can be very long, so I am wondering if it is possible to only call the SvnClient.Export method a single time with the list of files to export as an input argument.

Below is an example of the code I'm using:

```
            using (SvnClient client = new SvnClient())
            {
                foreach (RepoFileExplorer.RepositoryFile repositoryfile in repositoryfiles)
                {
                    string localfilename = System.IO.Path.Combine(localfolder, repositoryfile.Name);
                    try
                    {
                        SvnExportArgs args = new SvnExportArgs();
                        args.Revision = new SvnRevision(repositoryfile.RevisionNumber);
                        args.Overwrite = true;
                        args.ThrowOnError = true;
                        args.ThrowOnWarning = true;
                        SvnTarget target = new SvnUriTarget(repositoryfile.Uri);
                        client.Export(target, localfilename, args);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Message.InfoMessage("An error occurred while exporting the file " + repositoryfile.Path + ": " + ex.Message);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Thank you